# Class Company\Module\Console\ImageImportConsole\Interceptor does not exist

Tags: php, command, magento2

I am creating a custom command line to import images from M1 to M2.

I have created a command it is working properly. Now, I am trying to call my helper class in to console. But getting error -

```
In ClassReader.php line 24:
Class Company\Module\Console\ImageImportConsole\Interceptor does not exist
```

Here is extended command class -

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Console;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;

class ImageImportConsole extends Command
{

    const PRODUCT_ID = 'productId'; // key of parameter

    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(
        Company\Module\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    protected function configure(){
        $options = [
            new InputOption(
                self::PRODUCT_ID, // the option name
                '-id', // the shortcut
                InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, // the option mode
                'Optional Parameter. Product entity_id. It will start importing image from this id.' // the description
            ),
        ];
        $this->setName('imageimporttool:start');
        $this->setDescription('Image Import Tool');
        $this->setDefinition($options);
        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){
        $id = $input->getOption(self::PRODUCT_ID);

        // $helper = new Data();
        $this->helper->test();
        // if ($id) {
        //     // $output->writeln("Hi " . $id . ", Success!");
        // } else {
            
        // }

        $output->writeln("Success");
    }
}
```

When I try to build up gradation I am getting this error.

How to call helper class in command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after some research I have found a solution.

We have to pass `Magento\Framework\App\State` to call helper class.

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Console;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class ImageImportConsole extends Command
{

    const PRODUCT_ID = 'productId'; // key of parameter

    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(
        Company\Module\Helper\Data $helper,
        State $state,
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    protected function configure(){
        $options = [
            new InputOption(
                self::PRODUCT_ID, // the option name
                '-id', // the shortcut
                InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, // the option mode
                'Optional Parameter. Product entity_id. It will start importing image from this id.' // the description
            ),
        ];
        $this->setName('imageimporttool:start');
        $this->setDescription('Image Import Tool');
        $this->setDefinition($options);
        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){
        $id = $input->getOption(self::PRODUCT_ID);

        $this->helper->test();//this we start working

        $output->writeln("Success");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `vendor/` and run `composer install`.
2. Check for `Company\Module\Console\ImageImportConsole\Interceptor` - does it exists in your project? Maybe you just import this class somewhere else but it does not exists?

Everything else looks ok for me.

Comment: I tried to install composer again. But same error.

Answer (score 0):

Run command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento c:f
```